# Cannot use sitemap editor in openCMS

Tags: opencms

I'm a newcomer in openCMS. I cannot use Sitemap editor, when I clicked on .config file the window opens and the error appears:

> "Error reading resource from path "/.content/.config".Reason: Unable
>   to read resource "/.content/.config".

error log:

```
org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException: Error reading resource from path "/.content/.config".
    at org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException.createException(CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException.java:71)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDbContext.throwException(CmsDbContext.java:334)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDbContext.report(CmsDbContext.java:286)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsSecurityManager.readResource(CmsSecurityManager.java:4687)
    at org.opencms.file.CmsObject.readResource(CmsObject.java:2943)
    at org.opencms.file.CmsObject.readResource(CmsObject.java:2910)
    at org.opencms.file.CmsObject.readDefaultFile(CmsObject.java:2238)
    at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.initResource(OpenCmsCore.java:1396)
    at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsCore.showResource(OpenCmsCore.java:1595)
    at org.opencms.main.OpenCmsServlet.doGet(OpenCmsServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.opencms.file.CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException: Unable to read resource "/.content/.config".
    at org.opencms.db.generic.CmsVfsDriver.readResource(CmsVfsDriver.java:2163)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsDriverManager.readResource(CmsDriverManager.java:7310)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsSecurityManager.readResource(CmsSecurityManager.java:6922)
    at org.opencms.db.CmsSecurityManager.readResource(CmsSecurityManager.java:4685)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you under the right context? OpenCms cannot find `/.content/.config`... I guess you really want to access `/sites/default/.content/.config`? In that case, set the site context in your OpenCms explorer:

[image: Set site context]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something of this?

1. Check if  your in the right site
2. Check if you have the correct type folder, this will be subsitemap
3. Check you have the correct type in ".content" this have to be "content_folder" and the type for the .config have to be "sitemap_config"
4. Check if you have set the title on the elements type containerpage